# Dynamic Dropdownlist on ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

How to make a dynamic dropdownlist on asp.net?

I have a **dropdownlist**:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FirstParameter" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

A **label** and the other **dropdownlist**:

```
<asp:Label ID="SecondParameter_Label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

<asp:DropDownList ID="SecondParameter" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

When I change the selection on the `FirstParameter` dropdownlist, then the text on `SecondParameter_Label` should change based on the selection, and so for the `SecondParameter` dropdownlist, should be binding with the data filter based on the selected value on the first dropdownlist.

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
Protected Sub FirstParameter_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FirstParameter.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Change the label text
    SecondParameter_Label.Text = ReportType_Dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Value

    'Bind value to the SecondParameter dropdownlist
    SecondParameter.DataSource = dataTableName '--> Assumed that I already have the DataTable called from a class
    SecondParameter.DataTextField = "NameofDatabaseColumn"
    SecondParameter.DataValueField = "NameofDatabaseColumn"
    SecondParameter.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I have tried to change the `SecondParameter_Label` text first but still doesn't work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding AutoPostBack property to the dropdowns. You will also need to handle them on the server side. Your first dropdown should like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FirstParameter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```